# Best Indexing Strategy for Query with Equality[A], Range[B], Group By[C], AND Order By[count(P)]

Tags: mysql, index, performance, index-tuning, mariadb, query-performance

I have a poorly performing query:

```
SELECT  user_id, count(item_id) as count
FROM table items 
WHERE category = 'magazine'
AND created_at > 1384754400
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY count(item_id) desc
LIMIT 100
```

**Whats the optimal indexing strategy in order to optimize this query?**

### Table Details

**500million records** with the following structure / cardinalities:

- `PRIMARY KEY (item_id)` - cardinality: 500 M
- `user_id` - cardinality: ~ 25 M
- `category` - cardinality: ~ 2.5 M
- `created_at` - cardinality: ~ 150 M

Indexing:

- I have **individual indexes** on each the user_id, category and created_at fields

I also have the following covering indexes:

- (`category`, `user_id`) - *this is the one the query optimizer defaults to when running explain*
- (`category`, `created_at`)
- (`category`, `created_at`, `user_id`) - *this is one I attempted to create in order to optimize this query, however, it doesn't seem to be working very well*.

Comment: What does "mm" mean? Do you mean "m" as millions?

Comment: mm means millions.

Comment: no, "mm" means millimeters, and "M" means millions :)

Comment: @fejesjoco "M" could also mean thousand :)

Comment: M = 1024 * 1024 :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you ONLY want to optimise for this query. This is the best index:

```
ALTER TABLE items ADD INDEX (category, created_at, user_id)
```

This optimises the value of the filters, which reduces the total amount of data you touch. By adding `user_id`, `item_id` at the end of the query, you make the index covering and it saves you a lookup into the primary index.

We can assume that `item_id` is NOT NULL (as it is the PRIMARY index).

However, because the MySQL optimiser is pretty stupid, you may need to rewrite like this:

```
SELECT  user_id, SUM(count) AS count
FROM
(
  SELECT category, created_at, user_id, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM items
  WHERE category = 'magazine'
  AND created_at > 1384754400
  GROUP BY category, created_at, user_id
) AS d
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I would delete all indexes and start fresh. I think a category index is sufficient, or a (category, created_at) at most. Given one category, there should be around 200 matches, so it depends whether the created_at filter discards a lot of rows or not. Can you show query plans and numbers to verify how the query is performing? Also I don't know if it matters or not, but count(1) would be sufficient as well, instead of naming a column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're right that it depends on whether the created_at filter discards a lot of rows or not...but 200 matches might not be right.  For some categories, there are a upwards of 1 million matches.  The other issue with using (category, created_at) is that it adds a "hidden join".  It would need to get each primary key pointer, and then grab the entire row of data in order to get the user_id field value, instead of getting all of the needed field values straight from the index (a non-trivial, and large operation, since this table has many other columns).